# Widget not displaying in android but displaying in ios

Tags: flutter

I have a page written in flutter and when i render it on iOS it displays properly, but on android one of the widgets doesn't display. Can anyone help me figure out why?

Everything looks normal to me.

This is the widget

[This is the link to the widget code](https://pastebin.com/w6q1htcS)

This is where i'm calling it

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: const DecorationImage(
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
            image: const AssetImage("assets/images/background.png"),
          ),
        ),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(100.0),
                child: SizedBox(
                  child: Image.asset("assets/images/logo.png"),
                  height: 120,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,0,0,200.0),
                    child: LumiaFab(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 80),
                    child: FlatButton(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(100,10, 100, 10),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "Login or Sign Up",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color(0xFF009245),
                            fontSize: 14.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
```

[image: This is what it should look like, and it's how it looks on ios.]

[image: This is what it looks like on android. Notice the floating icon button isn't there anymore.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out FittedBox had a bug so i removed it. And then the margin bottom for the fab was making it hide under the stack for phones that were not as long as the iphoneX